# java URI changes in JDK 1.4 vs JDK 1.5

Tags: string, uri, java

```
import java.net.*;

public class TestURI {
     public static void main(String args[]) throws URISyntaxException
     {
        String first = new String("foo");
        String second = new String("bar");
        String third = new String("[space or another space]");

        URI temp = new URI(first, second, third);
        System.out.println(temp.getFragment());

     }
}
```

When I run the above code in JDK 1.4, I get

[space or another space]

When I run the same code in JDK 1.5/1.6, I get the following:

[space%20or%20another%20space]

Could somebody tell me what changed?

Thanks,
Raj

**Edit**:

If I do something like the following, it works:

```
import java.net.*;

public class TestURI {
   public static void main(String args[]) throws URISyntaxException
   {
      String first = new String("foo");
      String second = new String("bar");
      String third = new String("[space or another space]").replaceAll("\\[", "leftSB").replaceAll("\\]", "rightSB");

      URI temp = new URI(first, second, third);
      System.out.println(temp.getFragment().replaceAll("leftSB", "\\[").replaceAll("rightSB", "\\]"));

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the spaces got URI-encoded.

`%20` is the hexadecimal formatting of the ASCII space character.

I suppose spaces are illegal in the fragment identifier, which the implementation in Java 1.4 did not know.

From the [class documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html), emphasis by me:

> RFC 2396 allows escaped octets to appear in the user-info, path, query, and fragment components.
>   Escaping serves two purposes in URIs:
>
> - To encode non-US-ASCII characters when a URI is required to conform strictly to RFC 2396
>     by not containing any other characters.
> - To quote characters that are otherwise illegal in a component. The user-info, path, query,
>     and fragment components differ slightly in terms of which characters are considered legal
>     and illegal.
>
> These purposes are served in this class by three related operations:
>
> - A character is *encoded* by replacing it with the sequence of escaped octets that 
>     represent that character in the UTF-8 character set. [...]
> - An illegal character is *quoted* simply by encoding it. **The space character, for example, is
>     quoted by replacing it with "%20"**. [...]
> - A sequence of escaped octets is *decoded* by replacing it with the sequence of characters that it
>     represents in the UTF-8 character set. [...]
>
> These operations are exposed in the constructors and methods of this class as follows:
>
> - The single-argument constructor [...]
> - **The multi-argument constructors quote illegal characters** as required by the components
>     in which they appear. The percent character ('%') is always quoted by these constructors.
>     Any other characters are preserved.
> - ...
> - The `getUserInfo`, `getPath`, `getQuery`, `getFragment`, `getAuthority`, and `getSchemeSpecificPart`
>     methods decode any escaped octets in their corresponding components. The strings returned by these
>     methods may contain both other characters and illegal characters, and will not contain any escaped
>     octets.

You are using the three-argument constructor and the `getFragment` method afterwards. It looks like it should decode the spaces again, but it does not. This could be a bug, but the Sun Bug database seems to be offline now, so I can't really check this.

Comment: Thanks. The problem seems to be that any string given to the URI constructor which has [] in it doesn't get decoded by the getFragment function. One possible reason is that [] are reserved characters:        reserved All punct characters together with those in the string "?/[]@"